# Laravel MongoDB Indirect modification of overloaded element

Tags: laravel, mongodb, discord

Hi I'm trying to make a discord ticket bot with different presets for ticket panels, each panel has multiple options. This question is more about the web dashboard I'm making the goal is to be able to add options to a preset but I keep getting the error below. Normal I would use SQL instead of MongoDB but due to my bot using MongoDB I can't.

Code:

```php
 $this->validate($request, [
            'category' => [
                'required',
                'numeric',
            ],
            'label' => [
                'required',
                'max:50',
            ],
            'description' => [
                'required',
                'max:100',
            ],
        ]); 

        $key = 0;

        $ticketpresets = Ticketpreset::where('guild_id', $request->guildid)->first();
        foreach($ticketpresets['presets'] as $preset) {

            if($preset['presetId'] == $request->presetid) {

                $ticketpresets['presets'][$key]['options'][] = [
                    'id'            => random_int(100000, 999999),
                    'emoji'         => $request->emoji,
                    'label'         => $request->label,
                    'description'   => $request->description,
                    'category'      => $request->category,
                    'permission'    => []
                ];

                $ticketpresets->save();

            }

            $key ++;
            
        }
```

Error:

> Indirect modification of overloaded element of App\Models\Ticketpreset has no effect

[image: Laravel error]

[image: Database error]

Comment: If your model is casting `presets` as an `array`, you cannot do `$presets['index'] = 'value'`. check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) again. You must store the `array` in a normal `$variable` and then modify it.

Answer (score 1):

It got fixed here is the solution

```
        $this->validate($request, [
            'category' => [
                'required',
                'numeric',
            ],
            'label' => [
                'required',
                'max:50',
            ],
            'description' => [
                'required',
                'max:100',
            ],
        ]); 

        $ticketpresets = Ticketpreset::where('guild_id', $request->guildid)->first();

        $presets = $ticketpresets['presets'];
        $key = 0;
        foreach($presets as $preset) {

            if($preset['presetId'] == $request->presetid) {
                $presets[$key]['options'][] = [
                    'id'            => random_int(100000, 999999),
                    'emoji'         => $request->emoji,
                    'label'         => $request->label,
                    'description'   => $request->description,
                    'category'      => $request->category,
                    'permission'    => []
                ];      
                
            }


        }

        $ticketpresets['presets'] = $presets;

        $ticketpresets->save();
```